# Android Xamarin MenuInflater change from v 6.0 to later versions?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm writing an Android app using Xamarin libraries v27.0.2.1.  I also have references to Xamarin.Android.Support.V7.AppCompat and Xamarin.Android.Suport.V4

I'm unit testing on Android 6.0 and then testing on higher levels.  The following code causes the menu option in the actionbar to be visible and have the standard "settings" menu option.  It's fine on Android v6.0 but testing on v7.0 and higher, the menu icon (three dots) doesn't appear.  What am I missing?

Here's the toolbar xml:

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:minWidth="200px"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1" 
            android:title="@string/title_bar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />
```

I'm adding it to the layout using include:

```
        <include 
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
```

Here's the code to activate it.

```
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

As I mentioned, it works on Android 6.0 but not any higher versions.  I'm surely missing something simple, but I can't find it and haven't found any articles on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facepalm.  All I had to do was replace "toolbar" with "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar."

In the xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:minWidth="200px"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1" 
            android:title="@string/title_bar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />
```

And in the activity:

```
        //public Toolbar tbar = null;
        public Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar tbar = null;
.
.
.
            //tbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain);
            //SetActionBar(tbar);
            //ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            //ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            tbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain);
            SetSupportActionBar(tbar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.